# Capturar datos con getline

Tags: c++

Tengo problemas con esta función...resulta que cuando la ejecuto, se imprime en pantalla directamente: **nombre > fecha > ...**, y no puedo capturar el nombre.

Tengo las librerías `<iostream>,<fstream>,<string> y <windows.h>`.Si alguien me puede explicar porque pasa esto y como podría solucionarlo.
gracias!!

```
void Menus::menuCarreras(){
    int opcion;

    while (opcion != 6){
        cout<<"...SELECCIONAR OPCION..."<<endl;
        cout<<"[1] -> AGREGAR CARRERA"<<endl;
        cout<<"[2] -> BUSCAR CARRERA"<<endl;
        cout<<"[3] -> ELIMINAR CARRERA"<<endl;
        cout<<"[4] -> MODIFICAR CARRERA"<<endl;
        cout<<"[5] -> MOSTRAR CARRERAS"<<endl;
        cin>>opcion;

        if(opcion == 1) {
            string nNombre, nFecha;
            float nInscripcion;

            Carrera *nCarrera = new Carrera();

            cout<<"nombre -> ";
            getline(cin, nNombre);
            nCarrera->setNomCarrera(nNombre);

            cout<<"fecha -> ";
            getline(cin, nFecha);
            nCarrera->setFecha(nFecha);

            cout<<"Inscripcion -> ";
            cin>>nInscripcion;
            nCarrera->setInscripcion(nInscripcion);

            misCarreras->agregar(nCarrera); }

            misCarreras->mostrar();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola!!...la idea es que sean nombres para una lista de carreras (lista simple)...entonces que pueda introducir por ejemplo: RUN AND SUN  o algo por el estilo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seguramente estés pensando que  esta instrucción:

```
cin>>opcion;
```

No solo lee un entero sino que además limpia el buffer de entrada y no es así... en el buffer de entrada se queda el salto de línea como residuo. Sucesivas llamadas a `cin` eliminan dicho salto de línea y por eso un código tal que:

```
int a, b;
std::cin >> a >> b;
```

Funciona independientemente de que el separador usado entre ambas variables sea un espacio (o veinte espacios) o un salto de línea... sin embargo con `getline` no pasa eso. `getline` necesita que ese salto de línea desaparezca y para ello puedes usar `cin.ignore()`:

```
cin>>opcion;
cin.ignore(); // Elimina el siguiente caracter
```

Y listo, con esto tu programa ya debería funcionar.

Comment: Muchas Gracias!!...yo no conocía esa función

Comment: @Steven para eso existen portales como [es.so] :)