# ¿Comó arreglo un error al nombrar un archivo?

Tags: c++

estoy teniendo un problema al intentar nombrar un archivo.
Este es la parte de mi código que me salta este error:

```
Void Escribir_archivo()
{
    ofstream archivo;
    string Archivo_nombre;
    cout << "Escribe el nombre que quieres que tenga el archivo:\n ";


    getline(cin, Archivo_nombre);
    archivo.open(Archivo_nombre.c_str(), ios::out);

    if (archivo.fail())
    {
        cout << "El archivo no se pudo abrir";
        exit(1);

    }
    Texto_Usuario();
    archivo << text;
    archivo.close();
 }
```

Esta función es un método de una clase, pero cuando la mando a llamar, no toma en cuenta el getline y lo interpreta como si no se hubiese escrito nada, entonces, cada vez me manda a la condicional de que no se pudo abrir el archivo.
La función de Texto_Usuario() lo único que hace es guardar lo que el usuario digite, y eso será guardado después en el archivo.

Así tengo mi función Main por el momento.

```
int main()
{
     int eleccion;
     cout << "Bienvenido al Editor de Texto.\n"
        << "\nElige una opcion:\n"
        << "1.Para crear un archivo y escribir en el.\n"
        << "2.Para leer un archivo existente.\n"
        << "3.Para modificar un archivo que ya se haya creado.\n";
    cin >> eleccion;
    Texto prueba;
    switch (eleccion)
    {
     case 1:
         prueba.Escribir_Archivo();
         break;
     case 2:
         prueba.Leer_Archivo();
         break;
     default:
         cout << "Esa opcion no esta disponible, el programa se cerrara.";
         exit(1);
     }

     system("pause");
     return 0;
 }
```

No estoy seguro si el error se debe a la forma en como llamo las funciones. Ya que si tengo la función fuera del Switch, todo sale bien y no ocurre el error del getline.

No se que puede estar provocando este error, apreciaría mucho cualquier ayuda.

Muchas Gracias.

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Capturar datos con getline](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/158624/19610) (lo siento, me equivoqué al *clickar* en el motivo de cierre).

Comment: Sí, ya lo pude solucionar, tuve que poner un cin.ignore() antes del getline. Muchas gracias.