# Como puedo arreglar este error en mi codigo de c++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, ide

Estoy tratando de hacer el siguiente ejercicio:

> "Realizar un programa que lea un arreglo de estructuras los datos de N
> empleados  de la empresa y que imprima los datos del empleado con
> mayor y menor salario."

Tengo la estructura y el programa compila bien, pero el problema que tengo es que a la hora de ejecutar el código y poner el numero de empleados el programa se brinca el apartado de poner el nombre y solo puedo escribir el importe del salario.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std;

struct Empleado {
char nombre[20];
float salario;

}emp[100];

int main() {
int n_empleados, posM=0,posm=0;
float mayor = 0, menor = 99999999;

cout << "Digite el numero de empleados: ";
cin >> n_empleados;

for (int i = 0; i < n_empleados; i++) {
    cout <<"Digite su nombre: ";
    cin.getline(emp[i].nombre, 20, '\n');
    cout <<"Digite su salario: ";
    cin >> emp[i].salario;


    /*Determinando empleado de mayor salario*/

    if (emp[i].salario > mayor) {
        mayor = emp[i].salario;
        posM = i;
    }

    /*Determinando empleado de menor salario*/

    if (emp[i].salario < menor) {
        menor = emp[i].salario;
        posm = i;
    }
    cout<<"\n";
}
cout << "\nDatos del empleado con mayor salario: \n";
cout << "Nombre: " << emp[posM].nombre << endl;
cout << "Salario: " << emp[posM].salario << endl;

cout << "\nDatos del empleado con menor salario: \n";
cout << "Nombre: " << emp[posm].nombre << endl;
cout << "Salario: " << emp[posm].salario << endl;



system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Y esto es lo que aparece en la consola:

```
Digite el numero de empleados: 2
Digite su nombre: 
Digite su salario: 3500
Digite su nombre: 
Digite su salario: 4000
Datos del empleado con mayor salario:
Nombre:
Salario: 4000
Datos del empleado con menor salario:
Nombre:
Salario: 3500
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Capturar datos con getline](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/158624/capturar-datos-con-getline)

Answer (score 0):

En C++ está el inconveniente de que no puedes usar adecuadamente un getline() y un cin>> en el mismo programa, lo mejor seria que utilizaras siempre un getline() en vez de cin>>, para eso crea una string y utiliza stof() para asignarlo al salario:

```
//puede que necesites #include <string>
string s_temp;
cin.getline(s_temp, 20, '\n');
emp[i].salario = stof(s_temp); //Convierte la string a float
```

P.D.: Ten en cuenta que cada compilador de C++ podría tener unos parámetros de getline() diferentes, asi que mira la documentación si funciona incorrectamente.